# Style on AutoCompleteTextView dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've been trying to set the style of my dropdown for the autocomplete for some time now. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

The green area is the dropdown with alternatives. I would like to make that box smaller, since it does'nt look very good at the moment with my rounded rectangle.

How do i achieve this? So far I have only been able to adjust each line in it..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out myself 5 minutes after putting the question here. I'll keep the question up for someone who might come across this.

You can simply put dropdown attributes when you create the autocompletetextview.

```
android:dropDownWidth="yourWidth"
```

Coudln't find any xml attribute for setting dropdown backgroundresource but the programmatical way works fine:

```
autoTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle));
```

This way you can define how the dropdown should look with your own drawable. If you would want to change it with xml from resource, this is an approach:

```
android:completionHintView="@layout/your_layout"
```

Comment: xml equivalent for `setDropDownBackgroundDrawable` is `android:popupBackground` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#attr_android:popupBackground