# How to create my own dropdown view for AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, popupwindow, autocompletetextview

I'd like to add PgUp/PgDn button at right side of the drop down suggestion list of AutoCompleteTextView. I created my own popup window with the layout described above (the layout xml showed below). Could anyone let me know how to replace the drop down list view of AutoCompleteTextView with my own popup window?

Here is what I'd like it looks like:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@drawable/frame">
    </ListView>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/pageUpDown" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pageUp" android:src="@drawable/pct_up_icon" android:background="@null"  android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="" android:layout_height="48dp"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pageDown" android:src="@drawable/pct_down_icon" android:background="@null" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="" android:layout_height="48dp"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get this done simply, I would recommend you to design your layout (with two buttons) and set to your `AutoCompleteTextView` as below:

```
android:completionHintView="@layout/your_custom_view"
```

Later, you may customize your buttons' click events to perform the desired paging actions.

Comment: Thank you Wagas. Is completionHintView used for single suggestion item or the popup window that display the suggestion list? I need to replace the popup window. I tried to use the layout (in my original quation post) in android:completionHintView but got NullPointerException.

Comment: The NullPointerException was caused by sth else. But the drop down view is still the same.

Comment: perhaps you should try creating a custom viewgroup (EditText + PopupWindow) to emulate this behaviour

Comment: What I need is a drop down with two buttons like the image I just added in my original post. I think the completeHintView is used for the item that will show in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question myself some time ago, and found a solution myself aswell. Check here:

[Style on AutoCompleteTextView dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497295/style-on-autocompletetextviiew-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

use AutocompleteTextView, set high treshold "setTreshold()" and call showDropDown() on button click

code:

```
String[] values = {
"abc_0", "def_0", "ghi_0",
"abc_1", "def_1", "ghi_1",
"abc_2", "def_2", "ghi_2",
"abc_3", "def_3", "ghi_3",
};

 final AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv);
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, values);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
actv.setThreshold(256); // if not enough set Integer.MAX_VALUE
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    CharSequence constraint = actv.getText();
    adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint);
    actv.showDropDown();
}
});
```